# How to determine if an Entity has a NamedQuery

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, annotations, named-query

*Again, posting and answering a question for the benefit of others based on [a problem I had the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948103/transactionrolledbacklocalexception-clients-transaction-aborted-when-accessing).  Hopefully this saves someone a bit of time.  I was a little surprised this wasn't built into JPA's `EntityManager`.*

**How can I determine if an Entity has a `NamedQuery` annotation with a specific name?**

I need to determine if an Entity has a particular `@NamedQuery` before I try executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When annotations are nested, you can get the properties of the annotation to get it's children.  In the case of `@NamedQueries`, it's `.value()`.

```
public boolean hasNamedQuery(Class<?> clazz, String nameOfQuery) {
    boolean foundQueryByName = false;
    NamedQueries namedQueries = clazz.getAnnotation(NamedQueries.class);
    if (namedQueries != null && namedQueries.value() != null) {
        NamedQuery[] values = namedQueries.value();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length && !foundQueryByName; i++) {
            foundQueryByName |= (nameOfQuery.equals(values[i].name()));
        }
    }
    return foundQueryByName;
}
```